# Publish a list of "objects" to SNS in one message, then subscribe with a master lambda, feed to slaves

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Wondering if this is recommended.

With a master lambda, subscribe to an SNS topic where I publish a message which contains a list of source/destination pairs for s3. Say 100 per message.

The master lambda with then loop though those pairs and call a slave worker for each item in the list which will do the copy of S3 objects from source to destination.

I was originally trying to use SQS but SQS is not an event source for lambda. Cloudwatch Events are too murky as how you pass actual data as payload.

So wondering if my approach above is valid and will hold up, or if there's a better alternative.

Thanks